# code behind gridview databind how to retrieve col value

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am databinding my gridview in VB code behind. Because of this I know I can not refer to the NewValues when text is entered into one of the edit boxes. I need to retrieve the value of a column in the RowUpdating event.

Does anyone have a sample code or tutorial  on how to do this?

I have tried to do this in a multide of ways, but each of my changes ends up breaking something else.
None of these three methods is working....

```
Dim DT34 As String = DirectCast(GridView4.Rows.FindControl("Textbox1"), TextBox).Text

Dim TB1 As Label = GridView4.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).Cells(0).FindControl("Label1")

Dim tb1 As TextBox = GridView4.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).FindControl("TextBox1")
Dim IDVal As String = tb1.Text
```

In the following code, I am believe it is finding the control but it is not returning the value that was entered into the textbox.

```
Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(GRD4.Rows(index1).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
updateDescription = tb.Text
```

My field has been converted to a Template field in the Gridview instead of Boundfield.
Thanks.

Comment: How is your gridview edit set up? Are you using TemplateFields with ItemTemplate and EditTemplate, or a BoundField, or god-forbid, allowing the columns to autogenerate?

Comment: @Bill Some are boundfields and some are templatefields. The only ones I am now concerned with have all been converted to templatefields. AutoGenerate columns=false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on this page seems to work quite nicely...

http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/04/19/Manually-Databinding-a-GridView.aspx

Comment: Exactly, I need to capture in RowUpdating because I am manually coding the update in a Store Procedure.Row Updated is too late.

Comment: That example is only for gridviews that have a DataSourceID not a gridview that is data bound in code behind.